# To have two titles in the document at different pages with the same style

Tags: titles

I have one document that combines many documents: Pathoanatomy and Pathophysiology, for instance.
I want to start a new document from the body like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Introduction to Pathoanatomy Notes}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

% first document
 ...
% second document in the some body
\title{Introduction to Pathophysiology Notes}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
...
\end{document}
```

The output is the right but the style does not remain.

**How can you do the same but maintain the style of the title page to the second title?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for any `\renewcommand`s, the `titling` package already provides this functionality:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Uwe Ziegenhagen}
\date{01.01.1901}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\blindtext[5]

\title{Second item}


\maketitle

\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If there's a `\thanks` in `\author`, the previous footnotes are printed again in the following `\maketitle`s.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the second `\thanks` in the second `\maketitle`?

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to prevent `\maketitle` from `\@empty`ing `\@author`, `\@title`, `\@date`, etc. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@myheadings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    \let\subsectionmark\@gobble
    }
  \if@titlepage
  \renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
}
\else
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Introduction to Pathoanatomy Notes}
\author{The Author A}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\title{Another Title}
\author{The Author B}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for the fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the `titling` package. This answer shows how to use the commands from that package to put the titles into the header using `fancyhdr` and how to extend the package to support subtitles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% just for fun - if you are using a class which doesn't like this, just leave it out
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhf[ch]{\scshape \thetitle}
  \fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \pagestyle{fancy}

% if you would like a subtitle as well
\makeatletter
   \newcommand{\my@presubtitle}{}
    \newcommand{\my@postsubtitle}{}
    \newcommand{\thesubtitle}{}
    \let\thesubtitle\@empty
    \newcommand{\presubtitle}[1]{%
            \renewcommand{\my@presubtitle}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\postsubtitle}[1]{%
            \renewcommand{\my@postsubtitle}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
            \renewcommand\thesubtitle{#1}%
            \renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{%
                    \par\noindent \my@presubtitle\thesubtitle\my@postsubtitle}}
    \presubtitle{\begin{center}\Large}
    \postsubtitle{\par\end{center}}
    \renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\presubtitle \subtitle \postsubtitle}
\makeatother

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% just for sample text - don't use for real!

\begin{document}
\title{Introduction to Pathoanatomy Notes}
\subtitle{A Guide for the Perplexed}
\begin{titlingpage}% Note that this environment differs from titlepage - see package documentation for details
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
% first document
\kant[1-5]\clearpage

% second document in the some body
\title{Introduction to Pathophysiology Notes}
\subtitle{Anatomy for the Adventurous}
\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
\kant[6-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: Multiple title pages with subtitles]