# Making 2nd Title with the same style as of Title 1

Tags: titles

I wants to make the 2nd `\title` in the same document but with some additional text on it. I have tried but couldn't fix it. I failed to identify the used package as well. I am not sure which `package` I should alter.

I used the following code, but it generates 3 output pages: 2 title pages and one additional page with `tabular` information. The font style of third page with `tabular` is also different. I want the font like shown in the attached figure. Any suggestion please? 
[image: Title Font Style]

I have already tried these:

[Two 'maketitle's in article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/two-maketitles-in-article)

[To have two titles in the document at different pages with the same style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161112/to-have-two-titles-in-the-document-at-different-pages-with-the-same-style)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,   % Schriftgröße
DIV=12,          % Seitenaufteilung
BCOR=5mm,        % Bindekorrektur
ngerman,         % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
paper=a4,        % Papierformat
oneside,         % einseitig
titlepage,       % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
parskip=half,    % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
toc=bibliography,% Fügt das Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis ein
toc=listof,          % Fügt das Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis ein
draft=false,           % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
%    captions=nooneline     % Beschriftungen nicht zentrieren
 ]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{titlepage}

  \subject{\textsf{Assignment}}

  \title{Thermal Power Plants\\[6cm]}


  \author{XXX}
  \date{October 28, 2016\\[1cm]}


  \maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}

  \subject{\textsf{Assignment}}

  \title{Thermal Power Plants\\[6cm]}

  \begin{center}

  \vspace{20mm}

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \Large\textbf {Prüfer:}     & \Large\textbf {XXX} \\
    \Large\textbf{Betreuer:}    & \Large\textbf {XXX}   \\      
    \Large\textbf{Verfasser: }    & \Large\textbf{XXX} 
  \end{tabular}

  \end{center}
  \maketitle
  \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear, and your example can not be run so isn't really much help but your image shows a sans serif title so perhaps you want to remove all the `\Large\textbf` from the tabular and put `\Large\sffamily\bfseries` just before `\begin{tabular}`

Comment: Normally, you don't use `\maketitle` in `titlepage`, but maybe KOMA is different.

Comment: Yes, you are right. @David Carlisle Actually I haven't included the packages here because they were so many and I'm not sure which one should I include in MWE. But I run this with my packages, it works. I want to get 2 title pages of the same `title` font but the 2nd title page should also include the `tabular` information, in addition to the `title`.

Comment: @ArslanYousaf the point of the example is that people can run it to see the problem and test answers so for a start it should not have `\input{deckblatt}`  just make a small single file document that has the issue.

Comment: I've updated the code. Please see it. @DavidCarlisle But as I mentioned earlier, I have no clue which package should I include here, from my _Packages.tex_ so that this file can be run easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the tabular for the second title within the `\title` command, and you can't combine the environment `titlepage` with `maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,   % Schriftgröße
DIV=12,          % Seitenaufteilung
BCOR=5mm,        % Bindekorrektur
ngerman,         % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
paper=a4,        % Papierformat
oneside,         % einseitig
titlepage,       % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
parskip=half,    % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
toc=bibliography,% Fügt das Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis ein
toc=listof,          % Fügt das Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis ein
draft=false,           % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
%    captions=nooneline     % Beschriftungen nicht zentrieren
 ]{scrbook}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

  \titlehead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
  \subject{\textsf{Assignment}}
  \title{Thermal Power Plants\\[6cm]}
  \author{XXX}
  \date{October 28, 2016}

\maketitle

  \titlehead{}
  \title{Thermal Power Plants\\[6cm]
  \vspace{20mm}
  {\Large
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
   Prüfer:        & XXX \\
   Betreuer:      & XXX   \\      
   Verfasser:     & XXX
  \end{tabular}
  }
  }
  \author{}
  \date{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works but it shows the _Author Name_ and _Date_ on both title pages. I just want _Author Name_ and _Date_  on title page one, not on the second title.

Comment: And if I want to include `\titlehead` like `\titlehead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{header}}` , where should I include? For both title pages or do I need to include it just once. I have tried but it shows the first `title` page along with `titlehead`, second page with just a `titlehead` and third page contains `title`, `tabular` and `author`.

Comment: Answer updated, to remove author, date, titlehead  from the second page just add command `\author`, `\date`, `\titlehead` without parameter

Comment: It has worked.  Thanks @Salim Bou But in my case, even-though there is a place on second title I see a third page with just a `toprule`. I tried with reducing the given `vspace` but still it's there.